# count in where clause using hibernate criteria

Tags: java, hibernate

I have simple model of project with users. Suppose I need to select all the projects that have for example minimum of 5 users.
In sql it would be something like this (I haven't tried it, might be mistake somewhere):

```
select * from PROJECTS p where count(select * from USERS u left join PROJECT_MEMBERS m on u.object_id=m.user_id where m.project_id=p.object_id)>5;
```

In project model I have:

```
private Set<UserModel> users = new HashSet<UserModel>();
```

and its mapped like that:

```
<set name="users" 
    cascade="none"
    table="PROJECT_MEMBERS">
    <key column="project_id" />
    <many-to-many 
        column="user_id" 
        class="UserModelImpl"/>
</set>
```

Currently my dao looks like that:

```
Criteria hbCriteria = session.createCriteria(ProjectModelImpl.class);
hbCriteria.add(Restrictions.ilike("name", criteria.getProjectName(), MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
return hbCriteria.list();
```

How can I add create criterion that would select only those projects that have `criteria.getMinUsers()` users?

Let me know if you need any more code or mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
.add(Restrictions.sizeGe("users", criteria.getMinUsers()))
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution of Vlad is definitely better than this one. I let it here anyway to show you how Subqueries can be used.

Use a subquery:

```
Criteria hbCriteria = session.createCriteria(ProjectModelImpl.class, "project");
hbCriteria.add(Restrictions.ilike("project.name", criteria.getProjectName(), MatchMode.ANYWHERE));

DetachedCriteria count = DetachedCriteria.forClass("ProjectModelImpl.class", "project2");
count.createAlias("project2.users", "member");
count.add(Restrictions.eq("project2.id", "project.id");
count.setProjection(Projections.count("member.id");

hbCriteria.add(Subqueries.le(5, count));
return hbCriteria.list();
```

Answer (score 0):

use a detachedCritera first

```
DetachedCriteria countOfUsers = DetachedCriteria.forClass("ProjectModelImpl.class", "proj");
countOfUsers .createAlias("proj.users", "member");
countOfUsers .setProjection(proj.count("member.id");
```

use a alias on that property and then use that alias to create a restriction on it.

```
Criteria hbCriteria = session.createCriteria(ProjectModelImpl.class) 
hbCriteria.add(Restrictions.ilike("name", criteria.getProjectName(), MatchMode.ANYWHERE))
.add(Subqueries.ge(5,countOfUsers));
return hbCriteria.list();
```